# HttpClient exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null

Tags: java, apache, http

I have next code

```
    URL targetUrl = ...
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
    GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod();
    getMethod.setPath(targetUrl.getPath());

    HostConfiguration hostConfiguration = getConfiguration(targetUrl) //unknown lib code

    client.executeMethod(hostConfiguration, getMethod);
```

In some cases(on some hosts) I get

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null"`

on client.executeMethod call.

Why may this happen?

Comment: I was getting this error when I didn't write "http://" in front of my URL. maybe you should try too

Comment: Currently I debugged code. The cause is that host were not set to HostConfiguration  but proxyHost were set. So should I set host when proxyHost is set or this is bug?

Comment: You don't need HostConfiguration in this case, look at this tutorial: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a write exampe of proxy
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/ProxyTunnelDemo.java?view=co
In my case problem was in hostConfiguration creation

Answer (score 8):

The error message is misleading...

You must add the **protocol** in front of the host, something like `HTTP://` or whatever you want to use.
There may be other circumstances in which this happens, according to [this blog article](http://deepakmodi2006.blogspot.com/2011/05/javalangillegalargumentexception-host.html), but `setHostConfiguration` has been deprecated so this only applies to legacy code.

The client code should catch it earlier instead of failing so deep in the system, how can incorrect data go that far?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are using incomplete url or without protocol. For example
`String url ="google.com"`. Change it to `String url="http://google.com"`. It will work now