# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null

Tags: java, apache-spark

There are too many posts on this issue. I have tried almost everything and it works beautifully when I am running it on spark local.

But if I pass the url from config as a param and running on spark client, than its failing with the error

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null"

Here is what I am doing

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(5000);
 PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://myurl/dir/dirb"); 
client.executeMethod(method);
```

What else i am missing to make it work ?

Comment: This issue comes when there is incomplete Url, Please print value param when you pass the URL from config as a param. may you miss something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpClient exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host parameter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300861/httpclient-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-host-parameter-is-null)

Comment: @grog i already did whatever has been discussed in the other post. the issue still exists.

Comment: @AmitRai print is showing the complete url with https

Comment: After I used Broadcast , the issue got resolved.